# Stack Overflow Jobs para o Brasil?

Tags: debate

Galera estava dando uma olhada em **Stack Overflow Jobs**, achei esse recurso muito interessante isto seria possível de implantar no **Stack Overflow** em português? É uma boa ideia? Esta é uma ideia viável? Sei que existe já muito site apropriado para isso, mas acho que por aqui é mais interessante por que as empresas podem visualizar seu potencial por exemplo para resolver os problemas e suas habilidades de comunicação escrita, etc.

Comment: "...as empresas podem visualizar seu potencial por exemplo para resolver os problemas e suas habilidades de comunicação escrita..." foi exatamente o primeiro pensamento que veio a minha cabeça quando vi o Stack Overflow Jobs. É uma mina de ouro, tanto para o Stack Overflow, como para empresas de TI.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Eu não tenho dúvidas de que o SO Jobs seria uma boa ideia aqui.

Gostaria de poder dar qualquer notícia à respeito, mas a única coisa que sabemos é que "por enquanto não". Como qualquer grande mudança na plataforma, ou no que diz respeito à comunidade, nós precisamos implementar e amadurecer o conceito no site principal pra que depois possamos estudar como melhor levá-lo para os outros sites.

No momento todo nosso esforço está em ter certeza de que a integração como Careers e todas as novas coisas que vêm com ela funcionem direito sejam um passo na direção certa. Então, por enquanto, não temos nenhuma noção de quando (ou *se*) vamos ter um "Stack Overflow Empregos".

"Não sei" não é uma resposta muito boa, mas é o que temos por enquanto...

#### Atualização pros tradutores

Como a @carla apontou, as strings que fazem parte do SO Jobs estão no Transifex e foram traduzidas por vocês. Isso é uma tremenda falha da nossa parte e reflexo do quanto nosso processo de tradução está longe do ideal. É uma das coisas que queremos mudar em 2016.

Até lá, vocês merecem um descanço. O [projeto do SOpt no Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/dashboard/) é o mais avançado e completo de todos os Stack Overflow e isso é mérito de todo mundo que ajuda na tradução. Da nossa parte, há muito que precisamos fazer para garantir que coisas como essa (do SO Jobs) não aconteçam mais, então peço que *parem com as traduções por um tempo*, enquanto botamos a casa em ordem.

Quanto ao SO Jobs, realmente não sabemos quando vamos ter uma resposta a respeito de outras línguas. Mais uma vez, falha nossa de não ter um plano, e não tomar conta de todas as consequências de *não ter um plano*.

Mais notícias assim que possível!

Comment: A gente espera de 6-8 semanas, não tem problema :D

Comment: Realmente, seria muito util o stackoverflow jobs aqui no pt-br :)

Comment: Hmmm, ou muito me engano ou já vi strings do SO Jobs no Transifex. É possível que elas estejam lá e estejamos traduzindo inutilmente?

Comment: @carla Atualizei o post, com detalhes sobre a tradução. Era grande demais pra um comentário.

Comment: @Gabe Resolvi dar uma olhada nas traduções hoje e tenho impressão de que o SO Jobs está lá ainda, estou certa? Devemos prosseguir com a tradução ou ainda não?

Comment: @carla Ainda estão lá. Ainda não resolvemos o problema de controlar o que vai pro Transifex, pra impedir que strings que não deviam ser traduzidas fiquem povoando o respositório. O que não quer dizer que Jobs não deva ser traduzido... No final das contas, ainda não sabemos se/quando vamos ter Jobs em Português. Ou seja... não tenho resposta nenhuma pra dar, mas recomendaria não prestar atenção nas strings que parecem ser de Jobs, por enquanto.

Comment: @Gabe Também observei strings daquele novo projeto do SO de Documentação. Nós teremos uma versão traduzida dele ou também é para ignorar?

Comment: @carla Só vamos ter uma versão dele quando conseguirmos melhorar o sistema de tradução, pra evitar uma série de problemas. Traduzir as strings não é má ideia, porque vamos ter Docs um dia, mas como é provável que a maioria delas mude até lá, talvez não seja a melhor área pra se concentrar no momento

Answer (score 10):

Achei a ideia genial, deixa o Careers mais integrado ao SO, mas não acho que seja uma boa ideia implementar isso aqui no SOpt, pelo menos não por enquanto, acho que a equipe do SE deveria esperar o site amadurecer um pouco mais.

Não sei se estou certo, mas a nossa base de usuários não é tão grande assim para considerar isso vantajoso aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Não só a base de usuários, muitas empresas aqui no Brasil desconhece o SOpt e o Careers, e não os usam para procurar funcionários, porem creio eu que isso ira mudar no futuro.

Comment: Concordo, porem tendo a plataforma jobs teríamos incentivo para divulgar o nosso CV e tornar esta ferramenta mais popular, a ideia de QA + Jobs so maximiza o potencial do usuário, é um grande incentivo.