# Aqui posso postar trabalhos?

Tags: suporte

Acredito que essa não seja somente a minha dúvida, mas de muitos novatos aqui.

**Aqui na Stack Overflow, podemos postar trabalhos em busca de freelancer?**

Preciso contratar um freelancer para desenvolver um sistema de painel para streaming e gostaria de receber algumas propostas.

Aqui tem algum setor que faça isso?

Comment: Não, você pode usar o [carrers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) ou jogar o anúncio da vaga no chat(acredito que isso seja permitido);

Comment: Acho que não temos um guia oficial "Regras do Chat", mas acho/voto que é/seja permitido. Sugeriria postar na 2ª à noite, na 4ª ao meio dia e na 6ª de manhã. E pronto, acho que mais que isso seria spam. Será que podemos abrir uma sala específica pra isso???

Answer (score 9):

É verdade. Nós não somos, nem temos que ser, o Stack Overflow em inglês. A ideia por trás disso é evitar que a tentativa de resolver problemas que ainda não temos, e que talvez nunca tenhamos, acabe engessando e supercontrolando nossa comunidade.

Mas nós ainda somos e devemos continuar a ser um site de *perguntas e respostas*. Perguntas que tem respostas, que são úteis para outros programadores, que resolvem um problema. Uma oferta de emprego não atende a nenhum desses requisitos.

Não tenho dúvida de que a ideia é atraente, mas não é para isso que serve o nosso site. A própria sugestão de que essas perguntas sejam sempre fechadas (ou transformadas em wiki) é indicativo suficiente de que elas não cabem no nosso modelo.

Answer (score -7):

Talvez seria interessante discutir essa possibilidade.

[Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) sugeriu que nós [não somos o Stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com). Além disso, a [ferramenta Jobs não está apta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4708/stack-overflow-jobs-para-o-brasil) a ser adotada por aqui. Talvez seja um processo rápido para trazê-la, talvez não. Mas o fato é que poderíamos adotar uma forma diferenciada do uso dessa ferramenta maravilhosa que é o Stack Exchange como melhor acharmos.

### Ideia

Todas as oportunidades acompanhariam uma tag específica, inicialmente simples (job ou oportunidade). Se a ideia madurecer, poderíamos crescer para tags variadas como *período-integral, meio-período, estágio, freelancer*.

Para que não haja super-pontuação em contas de usuários que postam trabalho, esses posts seriam obrigados a ser **wiki da comunidade**, tornando-os não remuneráveis em quesito de pontuações no Stackoverflow Português.

As oportunidades poderiam tirar vantagem das diversas tags que já temos (PHP, Java, JavaScript, Ruby-On-Rails, AngularJS, Laravel, etc, etc). Dessa forma, alguém que acompanha a tag `Java` poderia se deparar com uma oportunidade em sua *front-page*.

Ainda não tenho uma sugestão concreta para as respostas, mas minha linha de raciocínio inicial seria que tais *perguntas* seriam sempre fechadas e impossibilitadas de ter respostas. Dessa forma, a empresa (*original poster*) deveria oferecer uma forma de contato na própria pergunta, evitando  brigas, debates e problemas com as respostas.

---

Essas são minhas posições iniciais. Acredito que uma comunidade desse tamanho poderia ter outras sugestões para debatermos e adotarmos sem a necessidade de nenhuma modificação da ferramenta que nos está disponível. Enquanto aguardamos o StackOverflow Jobs Português, tiramos proveito da melhor forma que pudermos do que já temos.

Comment: Vamos aproveitar e fazer um classificados para vender computadores novos e usados também, para dar oportunidade dos programadores com poucos recursos de fazerem upgrades nas ferramentas de trabalho. Talvez devamos também postar manuais de diversas linguagens, perguntando "quais são as funções e comandos do Clipper", e postamos community wiki com cada uma delas e suas descrições, afinal, nem todas as linguagens são bem documentadas. Pensando mais um pouco, me veio a idéia de fazermos perguntas e respostas sobre quais são as empresas de TI boas ou ruins para se trabalhar, para ajudar os colegas.

Comment: Em outras palavras, se começarmos a inventar coisa pra por no site, estamos fugindo do foco que é a grande diferença do SOpt em relação aos os outros. Pode ser que um dia saia alguma idéia nova que melhore o site no que ele já é bom. Mas acho pequena essa probabilidade, e não acredito que a proposta atual tenha a mínima relação com o site. Claro que há umas exceções, tem gente que traz o trabalho todo pro SOpt fazer, através de 1279 perguntas sobre o mesmo projeto, mas ainda assim está se encaixando nas regras.

Comment: @Bacco Bom, bem ou mal o [Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/) é uma maneira de responder "quais são as funções e comandos do Clipper" :D

Comment: @Gabe acho que ele estava tão preocupado em menosprezar minha sugestão que ele não percebeu que a maioria das coisas que ele ridicularizou o StackOverflow está construindo.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu não estou menosprezando, estou pondo numa determinada escala, pois este tipo de sugestão de "vamos acrescentar isto e aquilo" já andou acontecendo em outras ocasiões aqui, e o problema é que tudo que "parece interessante " não fica tão legal quando colocado numa lista de coisas que podem ser interessantes para outras pessoas. Quanto ao SO estar construindo, é justamente para não misturar com o funcionamento principal. Sugeririra olhar sem ser pelo lado pessoal, para entender a mensagem. Mas se entendeu o texto como "ridicularizar", o exemplo ficou melhor do que eu esperava.

Comment: Marco sempre presuma boa intenção :) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: Marco, o conceito da plataforma Stack Exchange é ser uma biblioteca de perguntas/respostas úteis para toda eternidade. Jobs e oportunidades são mais que efêmeros e dentro de `X tempo` não tem mais utilidade nenhuma. . . Não tenho nem idéia se pensou nisso ou não, mas por favor não delete sua resposta pois serve como referência do Que Não Fazer. Valeu!