# Deveríamos continuar a traduzir frases relacionadas ao Jobs e Documentation?

Tags: debate, tradução, transifex

Ainda não temos o Jobs para todos os sites da Stack Exchange e o [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217) já se pôs, como dito pelo próprio post no Meta Stack Overflow.

Pensando nisso, **deveríamos começar/continuar a traduzir frases relacionadas ao Jobs e Documentation?**

Podem ver a lista de *strings* relacionadas ao Jobs e Documentation [aqui](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/67384894?translated=no&q=Jobs) e [aqui](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/69334189?translated=no&q=Doc), respectivamente.

---

Aproveitando a pergunta, **serão removidas as frases relacionadas ao Documentation no Transifex?**

Acredito que poderíamos ter uma *"visão"* mais verídica de quantas *strings* realmente faltam para terminarmos a tradução do site. Sem contar que as vezes ficamos (quem traduz fica) perdendo tempo traduzindo aquelas que nunca serão usadas.

Comment: Como opinião, acredito que poderíamos continuar a traduzir as *strings* do Jobs, mas dando prioridade às que não estão relacionas a ele. Sobretudo, resolvi fazer esse post no meta para ouvir mais opiniões.

Comment: Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4711/91) (Stack Overflow Jobs para o Brasil?)

Comment: Semi-Duplicata talvez @rray? Respondeu completamente sobre o Jobs (mesmo sendo de 1 anos, 8 meses atrás). Acho que poderia dar uma abordada sobre o Documentation também (se deve traduzir ou não), o posicionamento do SOpt sobre o Docs.

Comment: O docs foi cancelado [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6229/91) do meta aponta para o post oficial do anunciamento: [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/1342547)

Comment: O Jobs esta relativamente ligado a todos sites da rede. Agora estou curioso, em que locais do Transifex, ou melhor que lugar das páginas "estáticas" do site é mencionado sobre o Jobs e o Documation? Não consigo me recordar de nada.

Comment: No Transifex existem várias *strings* que estão relacionadas ao Jobs e Documentation @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Sim, mas para que paginas exatamente? Pois o contexto de onde é apresentado talvez faça a diferença, entende?

Comment: Entendo, mas não são páginas prontas ainda (que eu saiba), portanto não estão no site, neste SOpt @GuilhermeNascimento. E me referia a um contexto geral das strings relacionadas ao Jobs e Documentation.

Comment: Não usei muito o transifex, mas não me recordo de nenhum plano no passado de ter o jobs nos sites primos. Será que não foi apenas uma confusão lá?

Comment: [Aqui](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/67384894?translated=no&q=Jobs) e [aqui](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/69334189?translated=no&q=Doc) @GuilhermeNascimento você pode ver algumas strings (se conseguir logar).

Comment: @Stormwind excelente, isso vai ajudar as pessoas que lerem a sua postagem a entenderem o que esta ocorrendo +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meu assunto favorito... Traduções.

Uma dessas respostas é bem fácil: strings do SO Docs não precisam ser traduzidas.

As outras são mais escabrosas. Por partes:

- Jobs é um caso complicado em que há a possibilidade de se ter essas strings em Português, ou qualquer outra língua, mas nenhuma garantia de que isso vai realmente acontecer, ou uma previsão de quando. Internacionalização de Jobs é algo que merece uma discussão por si só.
- A identificação dessas strings, Docs ou Jobs, esbarra no mesmo problema de contexto que atrapalha a tradução do site desde sempre: não sabemos como e onde cada string é utilizada. Não temos uma lista completa de todas as strings de Jobs ou Docs, categorizadas de maneira fácil de ser encontrada. Não sabemos onde uma string é utilizada, e não sabemos as strings utilizadas em um lugar.
- A reorganização do Transifex passar por nós conseguirmos resolver o problema acima. A ideia é, eventualmente, se tudo der certo, termos cada string categorizada por tags, que permitiriam a identificação correta do uso de cada uma. Esse passo ainda está longe, por desafios técnicos, e também pela falta de recursos voltados à isso no momento. Channels vem tomando quase toda a atenção da equipe de desenvolvimento.
- Assim como também é basicamente impossível saber quando a tradução do site será terminada. A falta de categorização também significa que temos um número, desconhecido, de strings defasadas que continuam no projeto. Não sabemos, das 1774 strings não-traduzidas, quantas dessas *efetivamente* aparecem em algum lugar.
  Então não sabemos o quão perto estamos de terminar a tradução de todas as partes visiveis do site. Essas 1774 podem ser todas Docs/Jobs, ou não serem mais utilizadas, ou serem usadas em lugares comuns e que não foram traduzidas ainda. Não temos como saber.

Ou seja: tradução é meu assunto favorito.

Há mais de 2 anos eu procuro um jeito de dar boas notícias, e há mais de 2 anos não conseguimos resolver os problemas que assolam as traduções. É um problema complexos, cheio de aspectos técnicos muito difíceis de contornar, e que não temos previsão de quando teremos uma solução.

Temos que tentar organizar as coisas com as ferramentas que temos. É o jeito.

Comment: Tava esperando a sua resposta!

Comment: @Stormwind Ela tarda mas não falha!

Comment: É o que temos para hoje, vai demorar aproximadamente de 6 a 8 semanas conseguimos terminar ;)

Comment: [Tradução do SOpt](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27048/traducao-do-sopt)

Comment: @Stormwind Como ambas são "marcas" do Stack, meio que nomes próprios, eu não acho que valha a pena traduzir os termos pelo menos até termos confirmação da presença deles no SOpt. Então eu deixaria como Jobs e Developer Story mesmo. Fica até mais fácil de achar depois